# python h5py bug when feeding multidimensional dataset

Tags: python, h5py

Here is my problem, it works in case 1, not in case 2:

```
import h5py
import numpy as np

data = np.random.randint(0,256,(5,), np.uint8)

f = h5py.File('test.h5','w')
f.create_dataset('1',(3,5), np.uint8)
f.create_dataset('2',(1,3,5), np.uint8)

print("case 1 before:\n",f['1'].value)
# case 1 before:
#  [[0 0 0 0 0]
#  [0 0 0 0 0]
#  [0 0 0 0 0]]

f['1'][0] = data
print("case 1 after:\n",f['1'].value)
# case 1 after:
#  [[ 75 215 125 175 193]
#  [  0   0   0   0   0]
#  [  0   0   0   0   0]]

print()
print()

print("case 2 before:\n",f['2'].value)
# case 2 before:
#  [[[0 0 0 0 0]
#   [0 0 0 0 0]
#   [0 0 0 0 0]]]

f['2'][0][0] = data
print("case 2 after:\n",f['2'].value)
# case 2 after:
#  [[[0 0 0 0 0]
#   [0 0 0 0 0]
#   [0 0 0 0 0]]]
```

Does anyone can explain to me what i am doing wrong?
(please do not suggest to create a np.array whith shape equal to my dataset shape, because I work with way more dimentions/size!!)

Comment: 'it doesn't work' is a bad way of reporting problem.  To help I have to repeat your calculations, and see for myself what errors or bad results it produces.  I shouldn't have to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't used chained-indexing when making assignments.  Instead of

```
f['2'][0][0] = data
```

Use

```
f['2'][0,0] = data
```

---

`f['2'][0]` returns a new array whose data is *copied* from `f['2']`. `f['2'][0][0] = data` assigns `data` to this new array. The assignment has no effect on `f['2']`.

In contrast, `f['2'][0,0] = data` modifies `f['2']`.

---

Under the hood, remember that `foo[x]` calls `foo.__getitem__(x)`.
and `foo[x] = y` calls `foo.__setitem__(x, y)`.

So `f['2'][0][0] = data` calls

```
f.__getitem__('2').__getitem__(0).__setitem(0, data)
```

- `f.__getitem__('2')` returns a `Dataset`,
- `f.__getitem__('2').__getitem__(0)` returns a NumPy array
- `f.__getitem__('2').__getitem__(0).__setitem(0, data)` modifies that NumPy array

Whereas, `f['2'][0,0] = data` calls

```
f.__getitem__('2').__setitem__((0,0), data)
```

Now it is the `Dataset`'s `__setitem__` method that gets called, which naturally gives the Dataset an opportunity to modify its internal data.